# AttributeError: module networkx has no attribute draw_netwokx_edges

Tags: python

While I construct the network from neighboring argo and RBF argo methods for viaulization, there appears the error message. But I can see the partial of the graph from output:

```
## 2D visualize two different argos to construct the networks
colors=["red","blue","green"]
shapes=["o","s","*"]
nei_mat=speclu_nei.affinity_matrix_.toarray()
rbf_mat=speclu_rbf.affinity_matrix_
## vivualize the network diagram
plt.figure(figsize=(14,6))
## Using neighboring argo
plt.subplot(1,2,1)
G1=nx.Graph(nei_mat)               ## Generate undirected graph
pos1=graphviz_layout(G1,prog="fdp")
for ii in range(3):                # Set color and shape for each type of point
    nodelist=np.arange(len(wine_y))[wine_y==ii]
    nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G1,pos1,nodelist=nodelist,alpha=0.8,
                          node_size=50,node_color=colors[ii],
                          node_shape=shapes[ii])
nx.draw_netwokx_edges(G1,pos1,width=1,edge_color="k")
plt.title("K-neighboring argo constructed network")
# Using RBF argo
plt.subplot(1,2,2)
G1=nx.Graph(rbf_mat)               ## Generate undirected graph
pos2=graphviz_layout(G2,prog="fdp")
for ii in range(3):                # Set color and shape for each type of point
    nodelist=np.arange(len(wine_y))[wine_y==ii]
    nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G2,pos2,nodelist=nodelist,alpha=0.8,
                          node_size=50,node_color=colors[ii],
                          node_shape=shapes[ii])
nx.draw_netwokx_edges(G2,pos2,width=1,alpha=0.1,edge_color="gray")
plt.title("RBF argo constructed network")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

And the error message shows:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_12496/2806880895.py in <module>
     15                           node_size=50,node_color=colors[ii],
     16                           node_shape=shapes[ii])
---> 17 nx.draw_netwokx_edges(G1,pos1,width=1,edge_color="k")
     18 plt.title("K-neighboring argo constructed network")
     19 # Using RBF argo

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\networkx\__init__.py in __getattr__(name)
     49             "This message will be removed in NetworkX 3.0."
     50         )
---> 51     raise AttributeError(f"module {__name__} has no attribute {name}")
     52 
     53 

AttributeError: module networkx has no attribute draw_netwokx_edges
```

and the output diagram:
[image]

Comment: netwoRk. You are missing a `r`

Comment: Oh...thanks for your reminder